# Trying to set variable as part of URL in jquery ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am trying to do a post using jQuery.ajax instead of an html form. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({

type: 'POST', // GET is available if we prefer
url: '/groups/dissolve/$org_ID',
data: data,
success: function(data){
    $('#data_box').html(data);
    }
});
```

Here is my problem:

When this was in an html form, the $org_ID that was part of the URL would actually pull the variable and send it as part of the URL. Now that this is in jquery, its just sending $org_ID as text. How can I get this to figure out what the variable, $org_ID is? I tried declaring it in the javascript but I am brand new to jquery/javascript and don't really know what i'm doing.

Thanks!

Comment: how was "it part of the html form" was it a hidden field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you rendering this in PHP? In that case you need to do:

```
url: '/groups/dissolve/<?php print $org_ID; ?>'
```

Otherwise, you need to do something like

```
var org_id = 'foo'; 
// or
var org_id = '<?php print $org_id ?>';
$.ajax({

type: 'POST', // GET is available if we prefer
url: '/groups/dissolve/'+org_ID,
data: data,
success: function(data){
    $('#data_box').html(data);
    }
});
```

Unlike PHP, you can't interpolate variables in javascript, you have to concatenate them with the string.

If you're trying to POST a variable (`org_id`) then you should put it in data:

```
data['org_id'] = org_id;

$.ajax({

type: 'POST', // GET is available if we prefer
url: '/groups/dissolve/',
data: data,
success: function(data){
    $('#data_box').html(data);
    }
});
```

While you can concatenate params onto your url to send them in an HTTP request, putting them in a data object not only lets jQuery do more work for you & escape HTML entities etc (and keep your code cleaner), but also allows you to easily debug and play around with `ajax()` settings.

Comment: Also it assumes that this javascript is defined in a PHP page.

Comment: @bokonic, appending +org_ID does seem to append the variable to the URL so that takes me 1 step closer. However, $org_ID is a variable defined in PHP. How do I get the org_ID variable which I now have to define in javascript to equal the PHP variable?

Comment: just do `var org_id = '<?php print $org_id; ?>';`, assuming you generate the JS in php. If not, you'll need to make an ajax call to a php page that returns the variable/some JSON...

Comment: var org_id = '<?php echo $org_id; ?>'; does not work but if i just set a static value like var org_id = 7;, it works fine. Does not seem to like the PHP code in there.

Comment: @Progger you're probably not passing the page with this JS through PHP; if you view source on the file is the <?php print $org_id ?> there? or is it blank (where there would be the <?... statement) -- if it's blank, then the variable isn't set in PHP. If it's the <?php.. statement, then you have problems w/ your server or you aren't running this through a server running php (likely apache)

Comment: yeah, it doesn't look like i am. I will continue to t-shoot the issue but i will go ahead and mark this as solved as I am close enough. Perhaps the 2nd part of my problem is out of scope. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear in the question where your data comes from, but you can use something like:

```
url: '/groups/dissolve/'+orgId,
```

or:

```
url: '/groups/dissolve/?orgId='+orgId,
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, concatinate

```
url: '/groups/dissolve/' + $org_ID
```